# Fully featured CSV parser for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, csv

Can anybody recommend a way to parse CSV files with options to:

- set cells/fields separator
- set end of record/row terminator
- set quote-character for fields
- support of UTF-8 strings
- ability to write in-memory CSV structure back to a file

I did try Text.CSV but it's very simple and lacks most of the above features.
Is there some more advanced CSV parsing module or do I have to write it "from scratch" i.e. using Text.ParserCombinators? I do not intend to reinvent a wheel.

Take care.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't recommend a ready-to-go, packaged-up CSV parser for Haskell, but I remember that the book [*Real-World Haskell* by Bryan O'Sullivan et al.](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) contains a chapter on [**Parsec**](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec), which the authors demonstrate by creating a CSV parser.

The relevant [chapter 16: Using Parsec](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) is available online; check the section titled *Extended Example: Full CSV Parser*.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old thread, but both [csv-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/csv-conduit/) and [cassava](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava) have most, if not all -- not sure about re-writing to the file -- of the features you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

A quick search on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/) finds [Data.Spreadsheet](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/spreadsheet/latest/doc/html/Data-Spreadsheet.html), which does have customizable quote and separator.

Comment: i think there is still a lack of good csv library: `spreadsheet` uses String and `csv-bytestring` does not allow to specify separator

Answer (score 4):

There is the [`Data.Csv` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava) on hackage. In case your distribution does not provide a package for it you can install it via cabal, e.g.

```
$ cabal install cassava
```

It can read and write (i.e. decode/encode) records from/to CSV files.

You can set the field separator like this:

```
import Data.Csv
import Data.Char -- ord
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B

enc_opts = defaultEncodeOptions {
  encDelimiter = fromIntegral $ ord '\t'
}

write_csv vector = do
  B.putStr $ encodeWith enc_opts vector
```

Currently, `Data.Csv` does not offer other encode/decode options. There are function variants for working with a header row. As is, lines are terminated with CRLF, double-quotes are used for quoting and as text-encoding UTF8 is assumed. Double-quotes in values are quoted with a back-slash and quoting is omitted where it is 'not necessary'.

Answer (score -1):

Cassava works in memory and is very simple library e.g.

```
encode [("John" :: Text, 27), ("Jane", 28)]
"John,27\r\nJane,28\r\n"
```