# is Haskell suitable for statistic analysis

Tags: r, haskell, statistics

The question is in the Title. Basically I'm looking for an alternative to R.
I've been using R a bit, there are some really good stuff about it (especially data.frame plyr and ggplot), however I really love Haskell and type inference, so I was wondering if using Haskell to do "simple" statistic analysis would be a good choice.

My basic needs are :

- read/write CSV
- import SQL table
- do some basic 'mapReduce' on the data. Which where R is great but I assume Haskell should be equally good.

However my experience with Haskell is everything is fine until you process realworld data. You always encounter performance issue (and soonish) because even though in theory you should write functional code and don't worry about what's the computer is doing, if you don't and don't use the appropriate library and are not an Haskell expert, stuff are damned slow.

Comment: A good approach would be to try and solve the same statistics problem in Haskell and in R, and see which is easiest for you.

Comment: Of course, I'm just trying to save time by using other people experience ;-)

Comment: This is a reasonable question. There seems to be an over-zealous approach to moderation on the R thread. Anyway, for what it is worth, here is a link to the Haskell stats package. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics  I think the question you need to ask yourself is how scalble will it be if I need to run some complex analyses later down the track

Comment: @John It isn't just the R subcommunity here.  SO in general frowns upon opinion-based questions.  This question is also too broad to be useful.  Of course you _can_ do statistics in Haskell, but the range of modelling packages is much smaller, so it depends what mb14 wants to achieve.  Specific, answerable questions like "how do I read a CSV file in Haskell" are better. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4773712/134830

Comment: I have both used R and Haskell for statistic analysis (and love Haskell much more than I like R) and my answer is: it depends. R has much more libraries, and common tasks (such as reading csvs) are much quicker done in R. Furthermore, R lends itself much better to interactive experimentation than Haskell (you can use ghci, but its support for graphing etc. is really not on par). On the other hand I find that Haskell is much much more maintainable. If your quick explorations tend to turn into long lived programs, then it might still be worth using Haskell.

Comment: @Richie, Of course you can do stats in Haskell. The question is : is it easy enough ( R being the standard) ?

Comment: @Paul. Thanks, maintainability is my main issue at the moment.

Comment: Check out the `lambda.r` package which facilitates Hasekll-style functional programming in R.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Brillant ! That might be the answer to my question

Comment: There's a new project called [HaskellR](https://tweag.github.io/HaskellR/) that addresses this. It looks promising but I haven't tried it yet.